# Gulp AWS Access Denied issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp

This is my first time setting up a Gulp task for publishing and my first time working with AWS in more depth than just using what's already been set up by somebody else.

The error I get when I call the task is `AccessDenied: Access Denied` and my code is:

```
gulp.task('publish-staging', function() {
  var publisher = awspublish.create({
    params: {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket',
      key: 'mykey',
      secret: 'mysecret',
      region: 'myregion'
    }
  });
  var headers = {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=315360000, no-transform, public',
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
  };
  return gulp.src('build/**')
    .pipe(awsPubRouter({
      routes: {
        '^index\\.html$': {
          headers: Object.assign({}, headers, { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' })
        },
        '^.+$': { headers: headers }
      }
    }))
    .pipe(awspublish.gzip())
    .pipe(parallelize(publisher.publish(), 10))
    .pipe(awspublish.reporter());
});
```

and my bucket policy is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1529361802241",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "statement-id-1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::848046242589:user/myuser@email.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "statement-id-2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "statement-id-3",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something obviously wrong with this or could the issue be elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it has something do with the Bucket's "Public access settings".

Try unticking the "Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects" & "Remove public access granted through public ACLs" like so:

[image: Public Access Settings Example]